# Upload image to s3 bucket - react native and node js

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, amazon-s3

Within my app a user can select a profile image and i would like that image to be uploaded to an s3 bucket when the user saves their profile data

I pass the image data (and json, which consists of name, email, telephone for example) from my app to an express server and upload there

At present I can pass the image data (the url it seems at present) to an s3 bucket and it saves

I don't think i'm actually saving the image itself though, as when downloading from s3 (manually) and trying to open on my mac it states it may be damaged and i cannot see the image

Feel daft for asking but how do i actually upload the image itself? Thanks

**React Native Side**

```
const handleFormSubmit = formData => {
  const jsonData = JSON.stringify({
    ...formData,
  });

  // Handle profile image
  if (imageProps && imageProps.uri) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('formBody', jsonData);
    data.append('image', {
      uri:
        Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? imageProps.uri
        : imageProps.uri.replace('file://', ''),
      type: imageProps.type,
      name: imageProps.fileName,
    });
    sendRequest(data);
  } else {
    sendRequest(jsonData);
  }
};

 const sendRequest = data => {
   let responseData;
   fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/api/update_user_profile', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    body: data,
  })
  .then(response => {
    responseData = response;
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(jsonData => {
    console.log(jsonData)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  });
};
```

**Server Side**

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

// Setting up S3 upload parameters
  const params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket-folder',
    ACL: 'public-read',
    Key: req.files.image.name,
    Body: req.files.image.path
  };

const stored = await s3.upload(params).promise();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Multer for uploading files to s3.

```
const multer = require('multer');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const uniqid = require('uniqid');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage });


// ? Posts new file to amazon and saves to db
router.post(
    '/:id',
    upload.single('attachment'),
    async (req, res) => {
        const unique = uniqid.time();
        const { file } = req;
        const { filePath } = req.body;
        const { id } = req.params;
        const s3FileURL = process.env.AWS_UPLOADED_FILE_URL;
        const region = process.env.AWS_REGION;
        const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
        const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
        const Bucket = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME + '/' + filePath;
        const Key = `${id}/${unique}-${file.originalname}`;
        const Body = file.buffer;
        const ContentType = file.mimetype;
        const ACL = 'public-read';

        const s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
            accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey,
            region,
        });

        const params = {
            Bucket,
            Key,
            Body,
            ContentType,
            ACL,
        };

        s3bucket.upload(params, async (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({ error: true, Message: err });
            } else {
                console.log(params);
                const newFileUploaded = {
                    description: req.body.description,
                    fileLink: `${s3FileURL}${filePath}/${id}/${unique}-${file.originalname}`,
                    s3_key: params.Key,
                };
                try {
                    const response = await postFile({
                        name: req.body.name,
                        attachment: newFileUploaded,
                        alt: req.body.alt,
                        user: req.body.user,
                        relatedID: req.body.relatedID,
                    });

                    res.status(200).json({
                        message: response.message,
                        success: response.success,
                        result: response.result,
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    res.status(500).json({
                        message:
                            'File upoladed but Db couldnt saved request (upload  by ID)',
                        success: false,
                        result: [],
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: I was under the impression (and correct me if im wrong) but multer was for uploading multiple images at a time? Im only looking to upload one at a time, or does it not make any difference as to how many, just using `multer` is generally used for uploading images in general?

Comment: Multer is primarily used for uploading files. You can specify the upload proccess on middleware like ```app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'))``` or ```app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12))```